# bootstrap UI glitch after upgrading to grails 2.3.2 and compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.0.2" . do i need to downgrade?

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

after Upgrading .. the UI is messed up. It appears to have messed up everywhere bootstrap is used . does anyone else have faced same issue ? how to resolve it show i downgrade the bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by downgrading to 3.0.0 ( bootstrap )

Answer (score 0):

When Bootstrap upgrades their styles, they change some class-names and styles. Its rarely directly compatible. And usually things could break. You will have to make corresponding changes in your ui.